# Зашить драйвера в iso Windoww XP

Tags: windows, администрирование, драйвер, iso-образ

Прислали железо ещё и с ssd, а по устанавливается только на XP.
Процессе разливки ОС XP много ошибок, по ним погуглил, пишет проблема с драйверами.

Подскажите годную програмку,что бы зашить в нее в iso драйвера.
Я работаю на linux and windows. Так что если под Линукс буду даже рад)

Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зашить драйвера в образ XP может программа [nLite](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/72185-sata-drivers-slipstream-into-windows-xp-cd.html).

ISO редактировать можно программой [xorriso](https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso) (windows/linux).